# EXCEL Click Through an shape to the cell beneath

Tags: excel, vba, image, shapes

To get a wider border than Excel supplies I use rectangle, i.e. an image with a transparent center which I can place over a cell to highlight it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRWkS.jpg)

However if I now click on that cell, for example to turn off it's highlighting, I select the image, complete with points for manual size change or rotation, not the cell.

If I could locate the mouse click that might work, or trap the click on the shape.

Any suggestions welcome
I've search here and generally but no-one else seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code into a regular module

```
Sub shapeClicked()
    Dim shape As shape, shapeName As String
    shapeName = Application.Caller
    Set shape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapeName)
    shape.TopLeftCell.Select
End Sub
```

Assign the macro to all the shapes you have (right click, "Assign Macro").
Now whenever one of the shapes is clicked, the routine will be called. By using `Application.Caller` you can figure out the shape that was clicked. By using the `TopLeftCell`-property of the shape, you can get the underlying cell - in this code, it is simply selected.

Comment: Thank you so much for a simple WORKING solution! 
I create these shapes with Shapes.AddPicture, is it possible to assign macro's to them in code at creation?

Comment: and thanks to Mr Google:
shpTemp.Onaction = "'" & activeworkbook.name & "'!macro_name"